# Access query: How to refer to listbox at a form

Tags: sql, ms-access, listbox

I have Access Datebase comprising mainly to tables and a query. The table `tab_Projects` contains the fields

- `ID`
- `Title`
- `Status`

with several recordsets for different projects.

The field `Status`refers to the second table `tab_Status` with the fields

- `ID`
- `Status`

The recordsets for this table are fixed to

```
|--|-----------------|
|ID|Status           |
|--|-----------------|
|0 | "in preparation"|
|1 | "accepted"      |
|2 | "declined"      |
|3 | "finished"      |
|--|-----------------|
```

For the purpose of a user application with Access-Runtime I have a formular `frm_Filter_Projects`with a a listbox `listStatus`. This listbox recieves the data from the table `tab_Status` and the user shall use this formular to filter the projects for different statuses. This listbox-elements are multiselectable.

A query shall use this formular and filter the datasets according to the selected elements at `frm_Filter_Projects.listStatus`

The SQL-code therefor might be something like:

```
SELECT 
   tbl_Projekte.ID, 
   tbl_Projekte.Titel, 
   tbl_Projekte.Status
FROM tab_Status 
INNER JOIN tbl_Projekte ON tab_Status.ID = tbl_Projekte.Status
WHERE tab_Status.ID IN ([Forms]![frm_Filter_Projects]![listStatus].[itemsselected]);
```

As long as i use
`WHERE tab_Status.ID IN (1,3)` 
everything works in the expected way.

How can I refer to the selected elements at the listbox within a query?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE tab_Status.ID IN (...)
```

cannot be dynamic.

Thus, use code to:

1. browse the `itemsselected` collection
2. build the static list of the selected items, say `(1,3)`
3. modify the SQL of the query